# Wacom tablet - how to map all of the tablet to only part of the screen?

Tags: tablet, wacom

Suppose my screen looks like this:

[image]

Is there a setting I can change to map all of the active area of a Wacom tablet to only the area on the screen that I've draw around in red, which in this case is the drawable area of a Google Jamboard?

I've checked under `Settings` -> `Wacom Tablet`, and also checked the Ubuntu man page for `xsetwacom` https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xsetwacom.1.html and I don't see such a setting.

Apparently the Windows version of the Wacom software has this functionality in it:
https://developer-support.wacom.com/hc/en-us/articles/9354476441623-How-can-I-map-my-Intuos-tablet-to-part-of-my-PC-monitor-

But that does not help much since I'm using Ubunu.  I'm using either Ubuntu 20.04 or 22.04 if that matters.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After referencing this site:

https://joshuawoehlke.com/wacom-intuos-and-xsetwacom-on-ubuntu-18-04/

and experimenting a bit, I came up with a series of commands that achieves the above.  First run:

```
xsetwacom --list devices
```

you will get output like this:

```
Wacom One by Wacom M Pen stylus     id: 15  type: STYLUS    
Wacom One by Wacom M Pen eraser     id: 16  type: ERASER
```

What you need for the next commands is the `id` of the `STYLUS`, so for example `15` with my device.  Then run:

```
xsetwacom --get 15 area
```

This gives the default area of the tablet (not the screen).  For example with my device which is a `One by Wacom Medium Graphics Drawing Tablet` [https://www.amazon.com/Wacom-Graphic-Drawing-Tablet-Beginners/dp/B07XW9WW98/ref=sr_1_3?crid=1TB1W3GYLGY6V&keywords=wacom%2Btablet&qid=1693168855&sprefix=%2Caps%2C255&sr=8-3&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07XW9WW98) I get this output:

```
0 0 21600 13500
```

So now you will have to make these numbers bigger (not smaller) to make all of the tablet map to only a portion of the screen.  You can do math calculations or use trial and error.  For my particular device and looking to draw only to the Jamboard drawable area in the image in the question, this command works perfectly:

```
xsetwacom --set 15 area -2450 -150 24800 16750
```

I'm using the left-handed Wacom tablet setting in Ubuntu so for me the numbers were backward which made it a bit more confusing, but with a few minutes and trial and error you can work it out.  Clearly in your case you will need to experiment to find your own numbers for your device and desired screen area.